# EvalSpec input_fn : case where the feature is an array

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have some trouble understanding some details of the Estimator API and `tf.estimator.EvalSpec`. 
In an `EvalSpec`, the user is supposed to give a `input_fn`. A call to input_fn is supposed to return `A tuple (features, labels)` .
As far as I understand, the features can be a dictionary keyed by "feature name" and whose values are a tensor of values. For instance, if I have a batch of 100 examples and a feature called "weight" I will create an entry in the feature dictionary that is a tensor of shape (100,1), with key weight, and with all the weights for all the examples, right?

However:

- what if my initial feature is already a tensor, like "size" which is a an array of 3 double values? How can I input it via the input_fn ?

And the question I'm mostly interested in:

- what if my initial feature is a variable-length array ? For instance my feature could be "prices of all purchased products", and it would be a variable-length array of doubles (this correspond to tf.io.VarLenFeature in feature specs). How can I send several examples of this via the input_fn ?

Are these types of features "compatible" with the Estimator API ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) API, but I have learned quite a lot with the S.O. community and will try to answer your question.

First, I would like to point you to this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub). This is currently the convention I use for my [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator)s.

You are correct in that the `input_fn` for both the `TRAIN` and `EVAL` modes are meant to be tuples in form `(features, labels)`.

So let us tackle your first question:

> what if my initial feature is already a tensor, like "size" which is a an array of 3 double values? How can I input it via the input_fn ?

Well this requires me to back track a bit, to your input of:

> batch of 100 examples and a feature called "weight" I will create an entry in the feature dictionary that is a tensor of shape (100,1),

To make sure I understand correctly, you are saying that, what if instead of a `Tensor` with shape `[100, 1]`, you have a `Tensor` or `[100, <size>]`, in this case 3 doubles, so `[100, 3]`?

Well if that is the case, that is no problem at all. In the linked [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub) a single example of the input has shape `[20, 7]`. So a `Tensor` of `[3]` is straight forward.

The short answer is that whatever you specify as the `features` part of the tuple is passed to `model_fn`. So you want to pass a `Tensor` of `[batch_size, size]` you return a tuple of `([batch_size, size], labels)`. However, as another user pointed out to me on S.O. I will impart you with the same advice - use dictionaries e.g.

```
my_data = # Tensor with shape [batch_size, size]
features = {'my_data': my_data}
...
return (features, labels)
```

For reference, let us example the `input_fn` of the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub), where I do the same things as advised above:

```
def input_fn(filenames:list, params):
  mode = params['mode'] if 'mode' in params else 'train'
  batch_size = params['batch_size']


  shuffle(filenames) # <--- far more efficient than tf dataset shuffle
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

  # using fio's SCHEMA fill the TF Feature placeholders with values
  dataset = dataset.map(lambda record: fio.from_record(record))

  # using fio's SCHEMA restructure and unwrap (if possible) features (because tf records require wrapping everything into a list)
  dataset = dataset.map(lambda context, features: fio.reconstitute((context, features)))

  # dataset should be a tuple of (features, labels)
  dataset = dataset.map(lambda context, features: ( 
      {"input_tensors": features[I_FEATURE]}, # features <--- wrapping it in a dictionary
      features[O_FEATURE]                     # labels
    )
  )
```

For simplicity, I will assume you are using `tf.data.Dataset`. If your data is not stored as TF `Record`s, you will need to replace  line 1.

```
  1. dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
  2. dataset = dataset.map(lambda record: fio.from_record(record))
  3. dataset = dataset.map(lambda context, features: fio.reconstitute((context, features)))
```

with however you construct your dataset, be it `FeatureColumn`, `from_tensor_slices`, etc and remove lines 2 and 3 since you do not need to recover your `(Sequence)Example` from TF `Record`s.

Now let us address your second question, variable length arrays.

It is just the same as above! wrap it in a dictionary and return it.

This is true with the notable exception of recovering your `SequenceExample` from TF `Record`s, where you will need `VarLenFeature`